# Anylogic: why is there an "error: impossible to resolve" during compiling?

Tags: anylogic

I'm studying Anylogic. Currently, I'm learning how to build a route for a bus. I use "carsource", indicating the point where a bus is supposed to appear; then I set a bus agent with the help of which I register the logic of the bus move. Within the bus agent, I specify two parameters - bus stops and their number. "Bus stops" is an array ("остановки") of all the bus stops located en route, and "the number of bus stops" is responsible for the bus stop where a particular bus is situated. All these parameters are kept in one "Bus class". Why can't I refer to the parameter "колвоОст" (the number of bus stops, that is) from the same class where this very parameter exists? Thanks!

P.S. You can see the screenshots copying the link below (!!!)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctRvi.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.колвоОст` inside the agent. `this` is a reserved word for the specific agent unit that you are referring to.
The same applies to `this.остановки[...]` because you have this parameter defined for each member of the Bus agent.

Comment: indeed, this is a pointer to the current object. but the compliment goes with the same error.

Comment: What do you mean by "compliment"? Anyways, is there a specific reason why you are doing the carSource->delay->selectOutput inside the Bus agent? Why not to do it in the Main with `agent....`?

Comment: I specified both the logic of the route and the bus agent within one class. Now I have access to the parameters. I specified the logic for “carMoveTo”: this.остановки[this.колвоОст++],
for selectOutput: this.колвоОст==this.остановки.length. 
If a bus is located at the bus stop, then the next bus passes this bus stop by, instead of waiting for the previous bus to drive out.

Comment: Well, that's a different question, related to the model logic. Please feel free to upvote and accept as answer so that others also can benefit.

Comment: I figured it out. The thing is that I set a bus stop in carMoveTo: this.остановки[this.колвоОст++]. This way, when a bus drives to a bus stop, parameter “колвоОст” is incremented by an integer of one. The next bus takes the new value of the parameter “колвоОст”. But then a new problem derives from that. I’ve got three bus stops. When buses drive to three bus stops in total, then value of the parameter “колвоОст” is inside the range of the “bus stops” array. 
How can I change values of the parameter “колвоОст” for each bus?